# Angular not display data returned from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very new to Angular.js and having an issue that I cannot figure out. This is my html

```
<user-details></user-details>
```

This is my angular code:

```
angular.
module('rtcTimesheet').
component('userDetails', {
    template:
        '<p>Hi {{$ctrl.username}}</p>',
controller: function UserDetailsController(globalDataService,$http) {

    if(globalDataService.getServicePath()) {

        try {
            this.username="name here";
            this.userId=""

            $http({
                method:     'GET',
                url:        globalDataService.getServicePath()+'login.php',
                params: {
                    t:      "log",
                    un:     "username",
                    pwd:    "123456789"
                }
            }).then(function(response){

                if(response.data.hasOwnProperty("HasError")) {
                    $("#debug").append("<p>ERROR: " + response.data.ErrorMessage+"</p>");
                } else {
                    username=response.data.name;
                    userId=response.data.id;
                    $("#debug").append(this.username);
                }

            },function (err){
                $("#debug").append("ERROR http: "+err.status);
            });
        } catch(err) {
            $("#debug").append("CATCH ERROR: "+err.status+"<br/>");
        }

    } else {
        $("#debug").append("<p>Unable to get service path...</p>");
    }


}
});
```

I know the data is being returned correctly, as I can output it using the

```
$("#debug").append(this.username)
```

When the page is loaded it just displays the initial 'name here'.  Probably has something to do with the slight delay of getting the data back from the database, but no idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable referance is incorrect. Check the code bellow to use `controllerAs` refferance with `_self`.

```js
angular.
module('rtcTimesheet').
component('userDetails', {
    template:
        '<p>Hi {{$ctrl.username}}</p>',
controller: function UserDetailsController(globalDataService,$http) {

    if(globalDataService.getServicePath()) {

        try {
            var _self = this;
            _self.username="name here";
            _self.userId=""

            $http({
                method:     'GET',
                url:        globalDataService.getServicePath()+'login.php',
                params: {
                    t:      "log",
                    un:     "username",
                    pwd:    "123456789"
                }
            }).then(function(response){

                if(response.data.hasOwnProperty("HasError")) {
                    $("#debug").append("<p>ERROR: " + response.data.ErrorMessage+"</p>");
                } else {
                    _self.username=response.data.name;
                    _self.userId=response.data.id;
                    $("#debug").append(_self.username);
                }

            },function (err){
                $("#debug").append("ERROR http: "+err.status);
            });
        } catch(err) {
            $("#debug").append("CATCH ERROR: "+err.status+"<br/>");
        }

    } else {
        $("#debug").append("<p>Unable to get service path...</p>");
    }


}
});
```